# Error Simulation Fluid, Domain scale and penetration Mesh problem

Tags: mesh, transforms, fluid-simulation, error

I'm trying to make a water source on a promontory, I've tried several tutorials but the problem remains the same. The liquid in addition to escaping from the channel, on the one hand penetrates the mesh despite being closed and on the other it does not. Also I would have to scale the domain, but once scaled the liquid disappears. I tried to apply the scale etc. but it does not work. If I need to add more descriptions tell me. Thank you
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can reproduce your problem and check it out. thanks.

Comment: the file is too large. how do i attach it? @Chris

Comment: You can use any cloudservice like Dropbox etc